# I get a 429 error when sending a request to steam

Tags: proxy, steam

I send requests to steam and immediately get a 429 error, and after a while my ip is blocked. Proxies are purchased. How can steam find out my ip?

`proxies = {'http':f'http://ip:port@login:pass'}  request = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Galil%20AR%20%7C%20Eco%20%28Field-Tested%29/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&country=RU&language=english&currency=5&filter=%22Sticker%22', proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': ua.random},timeout=10) print(request.status_code)`

I send requests to steam and immediately get a 429 error, and after a while my ip is blocked. Proxies are purchased. How can steam find out my ip?

I also tried https and socks5h in proxies.